# Simple Drupal sub-themeing...what am I doing wrong...?

Tags: drupal, themes

I'm trying to set up a very basic subtheme with Drupal.  I've been led to believe that the subtheme will inherit the settings of the base theme and the two themes will look almost identical.

Here are the steps I am taking...

1. Creating a new folder at '/sites/all/themes/sub_theme_name'.
2. Creating the info file 'sub_theme_name.info' in this folder.  Here are the contents...

> $Id$
> name = sub_theme_name
> description = This is a demo sub theme.
> version = 1.0
> core = 6.x
> base theme = garland

3. Browse to the Themes Admin page.  Enable my subtheme and set it to the default.
4. Browse to my front page...this is where I expect everything to look identical or almost identical to the base theme 'garland'.  The problem is that no CSS files are being inherited.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little gotcha in the [docs](http://drupal.org/node/225125).

> All style sheets defined in the parent
>   theme, but there is an option so this
>   can be controlled. Furthermore, your
>   subtheme *must* define at least one
>   stylesheet in order to inherit parent
>   stylesheets.

So if you define a stylesheet, even if it is empty it should work.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy!  I included an empty css file with my subtheme and now all the base theme's css files have been included as well!

Answer (score 0):

I reckon that you should start with [project zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen).